# How can 't I anchored a chart in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have insert a chart in  my spreadsheet, with some filter in the same sheet...

```
 chart = sheetTarget.getSheetByName('Foglio1').newChart()
  .asPieChart()
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .addRange(sheetTarget.getSheetByName('Foglio1').getRange('C:C'))
  .addRange(sheetTarget.getSheetByName('Foglio1').getRange('E:E'))
  .setOption('title','% ore di tempo impiegato per pratica')    
  .setPosition(39, 8, 0, 0)
  .build();  

sheetTarget.getSheetByName('Foglio1').insertChart(chart)

sheetTarget.getSheetByName('Foglio1').getRange('A1:F').createFilter()
```

In the same way I have insert other three charts, on the same column.

Problem: Charts are anchored also to row,  so when I use a filter, and some rows are hiddens, charts goes one on other,.....So is there a solution or a way to not anchor charts to row?

Comment: What happens if you remove `.setPosition(39, 8, 0, 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When you create charts and filters programmatically, they behave in the same way like when you create them through the UI

The charts need to be positioned somewhere (this is why you need an anchor) when you create them. And if you hide columns by filtering - the charts might have to move accordingly and might overlap.

If you want to avoid it, you need to implement some workaround.

E.g. if you know that you will be hiding columns - position your charts with enough space in vertical direction in the first place.

A thing you can do dynamically and programmatically is creating a function that on hiding columns will reposition graphs in a way you define, and another function that places the graphs back to their initial position, when the columns are unhidden.